# Hide dynamic sub menu items

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dynamic, menu

I have a dynamic menu which is running off the site map.  There is a situation where I need to hide certain menu items depending on whether a user is in a certain predefined role or not.  This works fine with the below code if the `e.Item.Text` is the main menu item, however fails when it is a sub menu item.

I have searched on google and here for a suitable solution but cannot find any.  To give some context to the below, the menu item `Mobile Devices` is a submenu of a menu item called `Requests`.

```
protected void MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (Role.RoleValue() == "User")
    {
        if (e.Item.Text == "Mobile Devices")
        {
            MainMenu.Items.Remove(e.Item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the standard RoleProvider for ASP.NET?

Comment: I am using windows authentication hooked up to the roles in Active Directory.  This works great for 95% of the times, however there are a couple of custom roles which I need to create which are not linked to AD, these are what is calculated in `Role.RoleValue()`.